# Filter ObservableCollection items on UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made an application that get some event scheduled from internet, this event are inserted inside a `ListView`, this list organize the content in `GroupDescription` like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Matches}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchNation" />
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MatchLeague" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Now, I've a `TextBox` where the use can search a specific item inside the `Matches` collection, what I'm trying to achieve is filter the collection with the given `search` string provided by the user in the `TextBox`.

What I did for now is a mechanis that use `linq`, create a backup of the collection and remove all the items that doesn't fit the user `search` string, but I noticed that this code is too heavy and also is too much code for achieve a simple UI filter.

I'm wondering if is possible create something like behind xaml. So essentially I've a bind in xaml to a property that get the search string provided by the `TextBox`, and when the value changed the `Matches` collection will filtered by the searched text, all of this through xaml.

Is this possible?

**Example**

Items avaialble in `Matches`:

- Hello
- World

The user search in `TextBox` => Hello:

in the `ListView` will be displayed only `Hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With performance, you'll probably have to try a few things and just measure the actual results to find the best answer. However, I think using the `Filter` callback on the CollectionViewSource makes a lot of sense. Basically, you would just assign the `Filter` property to a callback, which accepts the item from the source and returns a `bool` to tell whether or not it should be displayed. Here's an example:

```
// Create a view of your data, the listview should be bound to this too
ICollectionView _matchesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Matches);
// assign the Filter callback to setup filtering
_matchesView.Filter = FilterMatches;

// write the callback method, which returns true for items to display and false for items to hide
private bool MatchFilter(object item)
{
    // you can put any logic you need in here
    var match = item as string;
    return match.Contains(_searchQuery);
}
```

If the source collection or search query changes, then you'll need to update the collection view source too. If you have a `FilterString` property for example, which is bound to where the user is entering their search term, you could do something like this in the setter. The point is that you need to call `Refresh()` when something changes.

```
public string FilterString
{
    get { return _filterString; }
    set
    {
        _filterString = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FilterString));
        _matchesView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The main change is that your `ListView` needs to be bound to the collection view source to leverage the filtering built into that object. Otherwise, your listview won't be filtered if it's still bound to the actual collection. You could just make the view source a property in your view model or code behind of the view.

Comment: I must declare the ObservableCollection as static if I use .GetDefaultView, why?

Comment: You shouldn't need to make it static. It should be something like:
`ObservableCollection<string> _matches = new ObservableCollection<string>();
var cvs = CollectoinViewSource.GetDefaultView(_matches);
cvs.Filter = ...` The GetDefaultView() method is static, but you can pass a non-static argument to it.

Comment: Okay, to .Filter I need to pass the property like `FilterString` as in you're example?

Comment: Filter needs the method that will be used for your call back. In the example, I defined a method called `MatchFilter` that took an item and returned true/false for if it should be displayed, so I passed the method name MatchFilter to the .Filter property. You'll have a similar method defined, and that's what you should assign to the Filter property. Here's a good example I found where someone lays out how to use this method to solve a very similar problem to yours, maybe this will help clear it up. https://grantwinney.com/using-a-textbox-and-collectionviewsource-to-filter-a-listview-in-wpf/